# Dask Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner

Tags: python, dask, dask-ssh

When I run Dask on HPC in SLURM I got the following error.

Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/conda-envs/my_root/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2138, in _check_banner
    buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
  File "/conda-envs/my_root/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 367, in readline
    buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
  File "/conda-envs/my_root/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 563, in _read_timeout
    raise EOFError()
EOFError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/conda-envs/my_root/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1966, in run
    self._check_banner()
  File "/conda-envs/my_root/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2143, in _check_banner
    "Error reading SSH protocol banner" + str(e)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
```

Not like most of the other questions which mentioned this happened randomly, this happened to me every time.

My sbatch job is wroten in the following way.

```
#!/bin/bash 
#SBATCH -J myjobname
#SBATCH --nodes=6
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=20
#SBATCH --mem=64000
#SBATCH --qos=normal
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00


##### conda environment
module load anaconda3/2018.12

export CONDA_ENVS_PATH=/conda-envs

source activate my_root

### Get host name file.
srun hostname | sort -u > hostfile.txt

srun dask-ssh --hostfile hostfile.txt

### run program
python demo.py

echo 'Program ended at time:'
date
```

Answer (score 0):

To run Dask on a SLURM cluster we recommend one of the following projects:

- [Dask Jobqueue](https://jobqueue.dask.org/en/latest/)
- [Dask MPI](https://mpi.dask.org/en/latest/)

For more information, see Dask's documentation on deploying on HPC resources

- [Dask on HPC](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/hpc.html)